# Tileable subsets of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: set-theory, tiling

For $t\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ we set $t+A :=\{t+a: a\in A\}$.

Call $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ *tileable* if there is $T\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that

1. $t_1\neq t_2\in T$ implies $(t_1+A)\cap (t_2+A) =\emptyset$;
2. $\bigcup\{t+A: t\in T\} = \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Is the collection of tileable subsets of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ uncountable?

Comment: So you allow infinite "tiles"; otherwise there are clearly only countably many. Do you require the tile to be connected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Uncountable. For each set $P\subset \mathbb Z$ take the tile $A = (\{0\}\times \mathbb Z) \cup (\{1\} \times P) \cup (\{-1\} \times (\mathbb Z \setminus P))$.

Comment: Is the $\{0\}\times\mathbb Z$ part needed?

Comment: Just to make the tile connected